# Class applied to one UL gets applied to *all* lists on the page

Tags: css, styles, html-lists

Have simple document with two unordered lists.   The two lists are separate from each other in that one is **not** nested inside of the other.

See working example here: [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nAehw/)

A class is being applied to the First List, but not the Second List.   I'm finding that the class is being applied to all lists on the page, even when the other lists do not share the same class.

Markup:

```
                <style>
                    #listContainer
                    {
                        margin-top:15px;
                    }

.                   .expList ul, li 
                    {
                        list-style: none;
                        margin:0;
                        padding:0;
                        cursor: pointer;
                    }
                    .expList li {
                        line-height:140%;
                        text-indent:0px;
                        background-position: 1px 8px;
                        padding-left: 20px;
                        background-repeat: no-repeat;
                    }                   
                    .expList { clear:both;}


                </style>

                    <p style='font-size:1.4em;'>First list</p>
                    <div id='listContainer'>
                        <ul class='expList'>
                            <li>A<ul><li>A1</li></ul></li>
                            <li>A</li>
                        </ul>
                        </div>

<hr>

                        <p style='font-size:1.4em;'>Second list.  </p>
                        <ul>
                            <li><b>Cats</b>
                                <ul>
                                        <li>Cheezburger</li>
                                        <li>Ceiling</li>
                                        <li>Grumpy</li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li><b>Role Models</b>
                                <ul>
                                        <li>Bad Luck Brian</li>
                                        <li>Paranoid Parrot</li>
                                        <li>Socially Awkward Penguin</li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
```

Why would applying a class to a completely separate UL affect a different, non-nested UL on the same page?

**EDIT** - see the accepted answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14690435/why-is-this-selector-not-being-applied-to-the-given-tag) for a very good explanation of this problem.

Answer (score 1):

You're applying the style to *all* `li` elements:

```
.expList ul, li
```

...means "`ul` elements in element with class `expList`, and all `li` elements".

Since it *is* the `ul` that has class `expList`, I'm wondering if you actually want:

```
.expList li { ... }
```

Meaning all `li` elements in `ul.expList`.  Guessing though, hard to say without more info.

Comment: expList is a navigation panel.  That's the only place I want the class applied.