# Why is this selector not being applied to the given tag?

Tags: css, css-selectors

This selector isn't working like I might expect:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .someClass p, b {
        color:red;
        cursor : pointer;
    } 
</style>
<p>This is a test</p>
<p>This is another <b>test</b></p>
<p class="someClass">This is a test with someClass</p>
<p>This is another <b class="someClass">test</b></p>
```

**Results and [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/K238Z/4/):** 
Text for the non-styled paragraphs and styles appear black. 
Text for the `p` with class "someClass" is not appearing with red text, however the `b` with class "someClass" does appear red.

**Problem:** 
Why does the `p` class="someClass" *(third paragraph)* not appear in red, while the `b` class="someClass" *(fourth paragraph)* appears in red?

Both tags are included in the someClass selector.  I've not had much luck in finding an answer with searching, and the [documentation](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#class-html) doesn't appear to address this exact scenario

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want your style to apply to paragraphs and `b` elements with class `someClass`, use

```
p.someClass, b.someClass {
    color: red;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Your existing selector targets

- any `b` element
- paragraphs that are inside an element having the class `someClass`.

This code :

```
.someClass p, b { something }
```

is the same as

```
.someClass p { something }
b { something }
```

Comment: Edits acknowledges.   The problem remains -- why is the third paragraph not appearing in red?  See the fiddle for example.

Comment: Because the third paragraph isn't in another element having the class someClass.

Comment: Right - your logic makes perfect sense.  If this is the case, why then is the fourth paragraph's bold text appearing in red?  It's not inside another element with class someClass.  Just like the third paragraph.  Yet the fourth paragraph's bold text is red.

Comment: because your selector selects any `b` element without bothering about its class.

Comment: Thanks for the last edits to your answer, too.  Very helpful.